# What is reset, preset and clear in a counter circuit?

Tags: flipflop, counter, reset

I know this is a basic question. But I want to know the use of Reset, Preset and Clear in a Counter circuit.
How do I use them? 
An example would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of counter circuit? Do you have a specific chip in mind or something?

Comment: I'm very new to electronics, i'm using counters in general using j-K flip-flops

Answer (score 4):

In the kind of counter circuit you're talking about, "PRESET" or "SET" generally refers to forcing an output stage to a logical "1", and "CLEAR" or "RESET" generally refers to forcing an output stage to a logical "0".

Comment: Can you please give me an example based
on mod-n up and mod-n down counters.

Comment: Sure; edit your post with a schematic and I'll annotate it for you.

Comment: For example, I want to construct a mod-3 up counter.
From 000 -> 001 -> 011 again to 000.
What should I do with the preset and reset ?

Comment: Since SETs and RESETs can be either positive or negative true, it would be helpful if you'd resolve the ambiguity by just posting a detailed schematic of your circuit.

Comment: For an N-bit counters, `PRESET` will typically cause the state of the counter to be set according to the state of N inputs (for some counters the behavior is asynchronous; for others, the supplied state will be used instead of the next count).